# Kill -SIGINT not working from java but working from terminal

Tags: java, kill

I start a c program from java which collect data from a usb device and write to a file . like Below

```
Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime(); 
        Process cprocess = run.exec(command);
     cprocesses.add(cprocess);
    long id=cprocess.pid();
    cprocessesid.put(s,Long.toString(id));
     setCidglobal(cprocessesid);
```

when i want to close the file writing i send sudo kill -SIGINT  as below

```
        String command="sudo kill -s SIGINT " + cidg.get(sitearr[i]);
        Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime(); 
        Process cprocessaddr = run.exec(command);
        cprocessaddr.waitFor();
        BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new 
        InputStreamReader(cprocessaddr.getInputStream()));
        BufferedReader buferr = new BufferedReader(new 
        InputStreamReader(cprocessaddr.getErrorStream()));
        String line = "";   
        String output = ""; 
        while ((line = buf.readLine()) != null)
        {
            
            logger.info("Site id :"+site+" "+line);
            output+=line;
            
        }
        while ((line = buferr.readLine()) != null)
        {
            logger.info("Site id :"+site+" Error"+line);
            output+=line;
                
        }
```

I tried the same command from another terminal it is working as expected i also wrote to a script file with /bin/bash and try executing it but when I execute from another terminal it works but I execute bash temp.sh from java it doesn't work from java. I also tried process.detroy() that even not killing the c process gracefully and stop file writing

can I know why it doesn't work from java alone I'm also fine to open a new terminal run the kill command and close if that's the only solution let me know how to do that .

Comment: I'm guessing that the `sudo` command in your terminal has cached your credentials. I'm also guessing that the `sudo` command in Java hasn't, and that the `sudo` command is waiting for input.

Comment: Somewhat unrelated, you have a potential for deadlock. `waitFor` may not end if the process' output buffer is full. That won't be drained until you start reading from it - which you do _after_ the call to `waitFor`. See https://www.infoworld.com/article/2071275/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html for more information. Using `ProcessBuilder` with `redirectErrorStream(true)` can make it easier (no need for threads, as long as you read everything before calling `waitFor`), but you won't see the difference between regular output and error output anymore.

Comment: hi thanks removing sudo didn't help .I fixed by destroying the process and subprocess

Comment: I never said that you should remove sudo, because without it you probably don't have permissions. What I was implying is that you should provide the input that sudo was waiting for.

Comment: Oh thanks,it may help for people in future thanks  for your time.